# Error when the event is not triggered by keyboard

Tags: javascript

I have some instructions in `javascript` to be made when escape key is pressed. It's working fine until the event it's not  triggered by keyboard.

This is my code:

```
Fileinput.prototype.clear = function(e) {
    if (e) e.preventDefault();
    if(e.keyCode == 27) return;
}
```

The error that appears when the event is not a keyboard trigger, is :Cannot read property 'keycode' of undefined.

Tried an `if (e==undefined)`, `if(e.istriggered)` and it's the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Then your solution is simpel:

```
Fileinput.prototype.clear = function(e) {
if (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.keyCode == 27) return;
}
```

You already had the hint that the error happens on keyCode, not on preventDefault(), as undefined does not have a preventDefault function either.

Answer (score 0):

Almost your answer is correct just change as below

```
Fileinput.prototype.clear = function(e) {
    if (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return !e.keyCode === 27
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not returning me out of my function

Answer (score 0):

**keyCode** 
You should avoid using this if possible; it's been deprecated for some time.
Reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)

You may follow this code snippet.

```
  if (e.key !== undefined) {
    // Handle the event with KeyboardEvent.key and set handled true.
  } else if (e.keyIdentifier !== undefined) {
    // Handle the event with KeyboardEvent.keyIdentifier and set handled true.
  } else if (e.keyCode !== undefined) {
    // Handle the event with KeyboardEvent.keyCode and set handled true.
  }
```

because, this is all browser dependent.

Comment: How are you triggering the event. Can you post that code, which will give more clarity.